# Error: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am trying to run my application on a device. I have chosen my provisioning profile with the correct identities (code signing identity), then I have tried to run it, a message has displayed which is "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."
I have deleted all the previous profiles and certificates then I have done all the procedures again, and the same message has appeared.
[image]

Please I need your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these things:

- Make sure you're running the correct target and scheme
- Make sure you set the profile for the target/scheme that you're trying to run
- Make sure that you selected a development profile and are trying to run it in development/debug mode
- Verify in the Keychain Assistant that you have the development certificate and private key installed correctly
- Restart Xcode

I can offer you more specific help if you post screenshots of the actual build settings page and the target/scheme you are trying to run.  (Black out sensitive information.)

Comment: Thanks this was the list of things to check that put me back on track.

Comment: And never forget to make a clean build after restarting XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Debug Provisioning profile to debug your app in Device.

Comment: I want to archive my application to upload it to the app store, so i put in the debug profile automatic, and I've chosen my distribution for the distribution provisioning profile, shall I create a debug profile or it works automatic?

Comment: If you will build you project then it will show this error . If you will directly upload to app store then it will not show.

So better to create debug profile also.